# jquery datatable fixed first column with sub/child rows issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

issue is when click on button to show child rows the next rows first column can not collapse with there row, we fixed the first 2 columns of the data table because of table responsiveness while opening in mobile or tab.

[image]

in this image the yellow boundary part is fixed columns those are not collapsing with there row, and the blue border rows are sub rows of the red button click.
how we can collapse the fixed rows with there row ?

Comment: Can't really understand what you're saying, but some code would help.

Comment: what are you  talking about ? click red button show blue border content ? look  [jquery datatable document](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

Comment: look when i click on green btn it will open child rows which have subtask . its basicly the Task module that have a parent and sub tasks. so when i click on btn it collapse, therefor i fixed the first two columns of the table, when child tasks are open that fixed columns stick there they cant went down with there rows.

Comment: Here is the link that give you a example.   
https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: @DaniyalBaig provide jsfiddle or jsbin example. We will fork it and adjust for you.